# Currency Validation using RegularExpressionValidator in ASp.Net GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, validation

I have a GridView with a TextBox field present inside a TemplateField. The TextBox is bound with a `RegularExpressionValidator` control to validate amount field. Below is the code -

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txt1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Amt", "{0:C}")%>'></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="rev1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txt1" ErrorMessage="*" ValidationExpression="[\$]*\$?\d+(,\d{1,12})?(.\d{1,2})?" Display="Dynamic"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

The problem is the above code validates - `$1,2345678.00` but does not validates `$1,23,456,78.00`. I have noticed that if the textbox has more than 1 comma, it fails validation. How can I fix this regex?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean to say it does not accept `$23,456,780.00`? It is strange to see just 2 digits in a grouping. This one - `$1,2345678.00` - is also suspicious: why not `$12,345678.00`? Have a look at [`^\$?\d+(?:,?\d{3})*(?:\.\d{1,2})?$`](https://regex101.com/r/mH6sR9/2).

Comment: Does my suggestion work for you, or is the one posted sufficient?

Comment: This doesn't work. For ex -  this fails: $1,2398,000.00

Comment: Imho, that should fail. Anyway, glad you sorted it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you should escape the dot `.` in the last group. Other then that, I think it's enough to just add `'one or more quantifier': '+'` to the group which matches possible integers between commas. Like this:

```
[\$]*\$?\d+((,\d{1,12})+)?(\.\d{1,2})?
```

I hope I understood your problem correctly.